# How to deploy visual studio addin?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, deployment, installation, add-in

I have an Addin. I have the .Addin file and DLL file. I need to know what the best way of distributing this to people would be?
It's mainly for people in the office.

The way I got it on a friends machine was to copy the .addin and .dll file to the Visual Studio Addin folder, however I had to open the .addin in Notepad++ and change the Assembly path to point to where the DLL is. How can I automate this so the plugin can be installed and have the Assembly area get updated to the install path?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the assembly's filename in the `.Addin` file:

```
<Assembly>MyAddin.dll</Assembly>
```

No need for a full path.

Comment: That's great I'll try it out thanks.What if I wanted to make an installer for the plugin?

Comment: @AndyOHart: I use InnoSetup to make the installers for the VS addins that I sell, and I highly recommend it.